# Excel Sheet save as pdf

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that saves an excel file to the same directory as it is in.
This performs well and as expected.

What I want to do is to save the file as a PDF.

I have tried various bits of code but because I don't understand this stuff have failed badly.
Here is the code to save the file as .xlsm

```
Sub save_file()
  Dim path As String
  Dim filename1 As String
  path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"     'Same path as current project that the User opened.
  filename1 = Range("M1").Text
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs filename:=path & filename1 & ".xlsm"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

As I have found out it is not as simple as changing `.xlsm` to `.PDF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What I want to do is to save the file as a PDF

Use one of the following:

```
Sub SaveActiveSheetsAsPDF()

'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String
saveLocation = "C:\Users\marks\OneDrive\Documents\myPDFFile.pdf"

'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=saveLocation

End Sub

Sub SaveActiveWorkbookAsPDF()

'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String
saveLocation = "C:\Users\marks\OneDrive\Documents\myPDFFile.pdf"

'Save active workbook as PDF
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=saveLocation

End Sub
```

Source: [How to save Excel as PDF with VBA (10 examples)](https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-save-excel-file-as-pdf/#Save_active_sheet_as_PDF)

Comment: OK I got this far earlier, what i cant do is make the pdf save to the same file as the excel sheet. This path is variable the code i have works and produces a .xlsm but the pdf still eludes me.